# What is the topology on a vector space generated by a family of seminorms?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

I have a question about topological vector spaces. I'm getting so confused about what we mean by saying a topology generated by a family of seminorms.

At first, I thought it just means the initial topology generated by the family of seminorm functions. But then, I read about this sample, [Example 2](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/).

Let X be a set, then $\mathbb{C}^X = \{ f: X \to \mathbb{C} \}$ is a complex vector space. To each $x \in X$, consider $\| \cdot \|_x : \mathbb{C}^X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, ${\| f \|}_x = | f(x) |$. This is a seminorm on $\mathbb{C}^X$. The topology generated by this set of seminorms as $x$ varies over $X$ is the product topology on $\mathbb{C}$.

Why is this the same topology as the product topology on $\mathbb{C}^X$? If this is true, the property of initial topology would imply $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\mathbb{C}^X$ iff $|f_n(x)|$ converges to $| f(x)|$, for all $x\in X$. However, the property of the product topology would imply $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\mathbb{C}^X$ iff $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$, for all $x\in X$. Consequently, $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$, for all $x\in X$ iff $|f_n(x)|$ converges to $| f(x)|$, for all $x\in X$, which I think is not true.

Why do I get a contradiction here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $f\to g$ in this topology $\Leftrightarrow \left \| f-g \right \|_x\to 0$  and this happens $\Leftrightarrow  |f(x)-g(x)|\to 0$ for each fixed $x\in X.$ i.e. $f\to g\Leftrightarrow f(x)=\pi_x(f)\to \pi_x(g)=g(x).$ Thus the two topologies are the same.

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido I think the first iff "$\Leftarrow$" requires the vector addition is continuous in this topology, which might not be true.

Answer (score 3):

The topology generated by a set of seminorms is not just the initial topology they generate.  Rather, it is the initial topology that they and all of their translates generate (or equivalently, the initial translation-invariant topology they generate).  That is, for all $f$ in the space and each seminorm $p$, we require not just that $p$ is continuous with respect to our topology but also that $g\mapsto p(g-f)$ is continuous.  The idea is that for each $f$, we should think of $p(g-f)$ as a way of measuring the distance from $g$ to $f$, and so the set of $g$ such that $p(g-f)$ is small should be a neighborhood of $f$.

So in the example of the product topology, if $f_n$ converges to $f$, that means not just that $|f_n(x)|$ converges to $|f(x)|$ for all $x$, but that for any $f'$, $|f_n(x)-f'(x)|$ converges to $|f(x)-f'(x)|$.  Taking $f'=f$, this implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ converges to $0$, so $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$.

More generally, it is typical to describe a topology on a vector space by just describing the neighborhoods of $0$, and then obtaining neighborhoods of other points by translation.  That is what's going on here: when you say that a set of seminorms "generates" the topology, that actually just means they generate the neighborhoods of $0$, and neighborhoods of all other points are then obtained by translation.

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I understand this correctly, the topology generated by seminorms is the smallest one that makes seminorms continuous and the vector addition continuous? What about the scalar multiplication? It's already continuous when we only make those seminorms continuous?

Comment: As I stated it, the topology generated by a set of seminorms is the smallest topology that makes the seminorms continuous and make vector addition continuous separately in each variable.  This actually automatically makes vector addition jointly continuous and scalar multiplication continuous; you can prove these using the subadditivity and scaling properties of seminorms.